# Listener in Android service and stopSelf() occuring too early problem

Tags: java, android, service, listener

Consider such Android code in a Service implementing a Listener (events from orientation sensor):

```
public void onStateChanged()
{
    //do some work
    stopSelf();
}
```

I want the service to die AFTER the method `onStateChanged()` is triggered and AFTER its code is executed. However, it dies too soon - `stopSelf()` is being called BEFORE the `"//do some work"` occurs. If I place a break during the debug somewhere inside `"//do some work"` everything works fine - code is executed, then service dies. If I remove `stopSelf()` - code is executed. If i run it the way above - NOTHING from `"//do some work"` gets done. Why is that? How's that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible they occur in another thread. Some methods return straight away while their work is done concurrently. Depends on the "work". There might be a relevant onSomethingCompletedListener that you can use. Show us the code you've tried! And try inserting Log.d("blah"); statements to get more information.

Comment: 1. This is my own listener, which checks if the orientation of the phone has changed. There's no chance of having the event which would mark the listening done.

2. I insert a lot of logging! NOTHING gets logged unless I turn debugging on and I put a break somewhere in the code.

Comment: Peculiar. Here's a random idea: make a variable allDone=false; Then at the end of all your work set allDone=true; Meanwhile use a loop "while (!allDone)" before you stopSelf(); I'm probably way off and can't help :( If you post code we might get more clues... Android can be strange.

Comment: This is exactly my code - in "do some work" I have 1-line which changes the ringer volume. But I can remove it and replace with something else, still the same behavior. "While" thing doesn't work...

Comment: I dunno. Very bizarre. It might sound silly or obvious but keep trying other little things like waiting for a few seconds before stopSelf(), make sure your logs are refreshed (does logging work elsewhere in your code?!) and show us the actual code of stopSelf() and "some work" including variations. There must be a part of it somewhere that isn't doing exactly what you expect it to.

Comment: stopSelf() is from Android Service API. Loggin works fine. I'll try to attach my code later (it is really very simple).

Comment: This is so strange... I tried to reproduce this in another app - ok! I run my app again - ok! Maybe my phone has gone crazy or I have something wrong in my environment? Anyway, I will keep looking into this.